# Error of Property 'Value' does not exist on type 'number' in d3 Pie-chart in v4 using Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, d3.js

I have changed my pie-chart code from v3 to v4 and now i am getting the following error. It seems as if the code is not able to parse the data received though there is data received.

**Error Log:**

```
ERROR in src/app/views/d3chart/pieChart.componentTrust.ts(118,22): error TS2339: Property 'Value' does not exist on type 'number | { valueOf(): number; }'.
  Property 'Value' does not exist on type 'number'.
src/app/views/d3chart/pieChart.componentTrust.ts(171,28): error TS2339: Property 'Value' does not exist on type 'number | { valueOf(): number;
}'.
  Property 'Value' does not exist on type 'number'.
src/app/views/d3chart/pieChart.componentTrust.ts(172,35): error TS2339: Property 'Value' does not exist on type 'number | { valueOf(): number;
}'.
  Property 'Value' does not exist on type 'number'.
src/app/views/d3chart/pieChart.componentTrust.ts(178,39): error TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type '{} | PieArcDatum<number | { valueOf(): number; }>'.
  Property 'data' does not exist on type '{}'.
src/app/views/d3chart/pieChart.componentTrust.ts(181,39): error TS2339: Property 'Color' does not exist on type 'number | { valueOf(): number;
}'.
  Property 'Color' does not exist on type 'number'.
src/app/views/d3chart/pieChart.componentTrust.ts(196,28): error TS2339: Property 'Value' does not exist on type 'number | { valueOf(): number;
}'.
  Property 'Value' does not exist on type 'number'.
src/app/views/d3chart/pieChart.componentTrust.ts(197,35): error TS2339: Property 'Color' does not exist on type 'number | { valueOf(): number;
}'.
  Property 'Color' does not exist on type 'number'.
src/app/views/d3chart/pieChart.componentTrust.ts(204,38): error TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type '{} | PieArcDatum<number | { valueOf(): number; }>'.
  Property 'data' does not exist on type '{}'.
src/app/views/d3chart/pieChart.componentTrust.ts(207,39): error TS2339: Property 'Color' does not exist on type 'number | { valueOf(): number;
}'.
  Property 'Color' does not exist on type 'number'.
src/app/views/d3chart/pieChart.componentTrust.ts(222,28): error TS2339: Property 'Value' does not exist on type 'number | { valueOf(): number;
}'.
  Property 'Value' does not exist on type 'number'.
src/app/views/d3chart/pieChart.componentTrust.ts(223,35): error TS2339: Property 'Product' does not exist on type 'number | { valueOf(): number; }'.
  Property 'Product' does not exist on type 'number'.
src/app/views/d3chart/pieChart.componentTrust.ts(229,38): error TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type '{} | PieArcDatum<number | { valueOf(): number; }>'.
  Property 'data' does not exist on type '{}'.
src/app/views/d3chart/pieChart.componentTrust.ts(233,39): error TS2339: Property 'Color' does not exist on type 'number | { valueOf(): number;
}'.
  Property 'Color' does not exist on type 'number'.
src/app/views/d3chart/pieChart.componentTrust.ts(279,30): error TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type '{} | PieArcDatum<number | { valueOf(): number; }>'.
  Property 'data' does not exist on type '{}'.
src/app/views/d3chart/pieChart.componentTrust.ts(288,13): error TS2554: Expected 1 arguments, but got 2.
src/app/views/d3chart/pieChart.componentTrust.ts(290,31): error TS2339: Property 'Color' does not exist on type 'number | { valueOf(): number;
}'.
  Property 'Color' does not exist on type 'number'.
src/app/views/d3chart/pieChart.componentTrust.ts(308,26): error TS2339: Property '_listenToEvents' does not exist on type 'BaseType'.
  Property '_listenToEvents' does not exist on type 'Element'.
src/app/views/d3chart/pieChart.componentTrust.ts(313,39): error TS2339: Property 'Color' does not exist on type 'number | { valueOf(): number;
}'.
  Property 'Color' does not exist on type 'number'.
src/app/views/d3chart/pieChart.componentTrust.ts(340,41): error TS2339: Property 'Product' does not exist on type 'number | { valueOf(): number; }'.
  Property 'Product' does not exist on type 'number'.
src/app/views/d3chart/pieChart.componentTrust.ts(340,66): error TS2339: Property 'Value' does not exist on type 'number | { valueOf(): number;
}'.
  Property 'Value' does not exist on type 'number'.
```

**.ts File:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges, ViewChild, ElementRef, Input, ViewEncapsulation, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import * as d3 from "d3";
import { pie } from 'd3-shape';


@Component({
    selector: 'pieChartTrust',
    template: `<div #chart></div>`,
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class PieChartComponentTrust implements OnInit, OnChanges {
    @ViewChild('chart') private chartContainer: ElementRef;
    @Input() private data: Array<any>;
    @Input() private id: any;
    @Input() private applyFiltering: boolean;
    // @Input() private drillDetail:any;
    @Input() private isDonut: boolean; 
    @Input() flagMax: any;
    // @Input() private viewType:any;
    @Output() private chartClickEvent = new EventEmitter();
    @Output() private chartHoverEvent = new EventEmitter();
    @Input() defaultItem: any;
    private margin: any = { top: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0 };
    private chart: any;
    private width: number;
    private height: number;
    private host: d3.Selection<d3.BaseType, any, HTMLElement, any>;
    private svg: d3.Selection<d3.BaseType, any, HTMLElement, any>;
    private htmlElement: HTMLElement;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
        //debugger;
        if (this.data) {
            this.setup();

        }
    }

    ngOnChanges() {
        //debugger;
        if (this.data) {
            this.setup();

        }
    }
    public setup() {

        this.htmlElement = this.chartContainer.nativeElement;
        let chartID = this.id;
        let chartComponent = this;
        this.width = this.htmlElement.offsetWidth - this.margin.left - this.margin.right;
        this.height = this.htmlElement.offsetHeight - this.margin.top - this.margin.bottom;
        console.log(this.height);
        this.host = d3.select(this.htmlElement);
        // let data = this.data;

        let data = this.data.filter(obj =>
            obj.Value != 0
        );
        console.log(data);
        let innerRadius = 0;
        let outerRadius = 0;
        let width = this.width;
        let height = this.height;
        let isDonut = this.isDonut;
        let legendLength = 0;
        let legendMaxChar = "";
        //   let viewType = this.viewType;
        var tooltip = d3.select("body")
            .append("div")
            .style("position", "absolute")
            .style("z-index", "10")
            .style("display", "none")
            .style("background", "white")
            .style("color", "black")
            .style("opacity", 0.7)
            .style("font-weight", "600")
            .text("a simple tooltip");
        // Globals
        // Globals
        //this.width = 200;
        var countLegend = 0;
        data.forEach(element => {
            if (element.Product.length > legendMaxChar.length)
                legendMaxChar = element.Product;
            countLegend++;
        });
        legendMaxChar = legendMaxChar + "10000";
        debugger;
        legendLength = getTextWidth(legendMaxChar, "9", "sans-serif");
        var relatedHeight;

        var size: any = { width: window.innerWidth || document.body.clientWidth, height: window.innerHeight || document.body.clientHeight };

        relatedHeight = size.height / 3;

        height = relatedHeight / 2;

        width = Math.round(this.width - legendLength);

        var margin = 10,
            radius = Math.min(width - margin, height - margin) / 2.4;
        // radius = 60;
        if (isDonut) {
            outerRadius = radius / 1.7;
            innerRadius = radius;
            this.width = this.width -25;
            width = width - 25;
        }
        else {
            outerRadius = radius;
        }

        // Pie layout will use the "val" property of each data object entry
    var pieChart = d3.pie().sort(null).value(function (d) {
        return d.Value;
    }),

            arc = d3.arc().outerRadius(outerRadius).innerRadius(innerRadius),
            MAX_SECTORS = 15; // Less than 20 please
        //  colors = d3.scale.category20();

        // Synthetic data generation ------------------------------------------------

        // --------------------------------------------------------------------------

        // SVG elements init
        var tempHeight = height;
        // if (countLegend > 6) {
        tempHeight = tempHeight ;
        // }
        this.host.html("");
        var svg = this.host.append("svg").attr("width", width + legendLength).attr("height", tempHeight),
            defs = svg.append("svg:defs"),
            // Declare a main gradient with the dimensions for all gradient entries to refer
            // The pie sectors container
            arcGroup = svg.append("svg:g")
                .attr("class", "arcGroup")
                .attr("filter", "url(#shadow)")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width / 2.1) + "," + (tempHeight / 2) + ")"),

            btn = svg.append("button")
                .text("wiggle")
                .attr("transform", "translate(2, 8)")
                .attr("float", "left")
                .attr("class", "btnChart")
                .on("click", updateGraph),
            // Draw legend
            legend = svg.append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(-10,0)")
                .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
                .attr("font-size", 9)
                .attr("text-anchor", "end")
                .selectAll("g")
                .data(pieChart(data))
                .enter().append("g")
                .attr("transform", function (d, i) { return "translate(0," + (i + 1) * 16 + ")"; })
                .attr("curosr", this.applyFiltering ? "pointer" : "default")
        // Above line added by Madhavi on 25th July 2018 for Pointer on maximize

        legend.append("text")
            .attr("x", this.width - legendLength + 15)
            .attr("y", 5)
            .attr("dy", "0.32em")
            .attr("curosr", this.applyFiltering ? "pointer" : "default")
            //.attr("text-decoration", "underline")
            .attr("class", this.applyFiltering ? "legendpie" : "")
            .text(function (d) {
                if (d.data.Value > 0)
                    return d.data.Value
            })
            .on("click", function (d) {
                if (chartComponent.applyFiltering) {
                    var paths = arcGroup.selectAll("path")
                        .data(pieChart(data), function (dt) {
                            return dt.data.Product;
                        });
                    paths.attr('fill', function (dt) {
                        return d.data.Color;
                    });
                }
                d['chartID'] = chartID;
                if (chartComponent.applyFiltering) {
                    chartComponent.chartClickEvent.emit(d);
                }
            });

        legend.append("rect")
            .attr("x", this.width - legendLength + 20)
            .attr("y", 0)
            .attr("width", 10)
            .attr("height", 10)
            .attr("fill", function (d) {
                if (d.data.Value > 0)
                    return d.data.Color;
            })
            .attr("cursor", this.applyFiltering ? "pointer" : "default")
            .on("click", function (d) {
                if (chartComponent.applyFiltering) {
                    var paths = arcGroup.selectAll("path")
                        .data(pieChart(data), function (d) {
                            return d.data.Product;
                        });
                    paths.attr('fill', function (dt) {
                        return d.data.Color;
                    });
                }
                d['chartID'] = chartID;
                if (chartComponent.applyFiltering) {
                    chartComponent.chartClickEvent.emit(d);
                }
            });
        legend.append("text")
            .attr("x", this.width - legendLength + 35)
            .attr("y", 5)
            .attr("text-anchor", "start")
            .attr("dy", "0.32em")
            .attr("cursor", this.applyFiltering ? "pointer" : "default")
            .text(function (d) {
                if (d.data.Value > 0)
                    return d.data.Product;
            })
            .on("click", function (d) {
                if (chartComponent.applyFiltering) {
                    var paths = arcGroup.selectAll("path")
                        .data(pieChart(data), function (d) {
                            return d.data.Product;
                        });
                    paths.attr('fill', function (dt) {

                        return d.data.Color;

                    });
                }
                d['chartID'] = chartID;
                if (chartComponent.applyFiltering) {
                    chartComponent.chartClickEvent.emit(d);
                }
            });

        // Declare shadow filter
        var shadow = defs.append("filter").attr("id", "shadow")
            .attr("filterUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")
            .attr("x", -1 * (this.width / 2)).attr("y", -1 * (this.height / 2))
            .attr("width", this.width).attr("height", this.height);
        shadow.append("feGaussianBlur")
            .attr("in", "SourceAlpha")
            .attr("stdDeviation", "4")
            .attr("result", "blur");
        shadow.append("feOffset")
            .attr("in", "blur")
            .attr("dx", "4").attr("dy", "4")
            .attr("result", "offsetBlur");
        shadow.append("feBlend")
            .attr("in", "SourceGraphic")
            .attr("in2", "offsetBlur")
            .attr("mode", "normal");

        // Redraw the graph given a certain level of data
        function updateGraph(cat) {
            var currData = data;

            // Create a gradient for each entry (each entry identified by its unique category)
            var gradients = defs.selectAll(".gradient").data(currData, function (d) {
                return d.Product;
            });
            gradients.enter().append("svg:radialGradient")
                .attr("id", function (d, i) {
                    return "gradient" + d.Product;
                })
                .attr("class", "gradient")
                .attr("xlink:href", "#master");
            gradients.append("svg:stop").attr("offset", "0%").attr("stop-color", getColor);

            var paths = arcGroup.selectAll("path")
                .data(pieChart(currData), function (d) {
                    return d.data.Product;
                });


            paths.enter().append("svg:path")
                .attr("class", chartComponent.applyFiltering ? "sector" : "");


            // Each sector will refer to its gradient fill
            paths.attr("fill", function (d, i) {
                // Added By Madhavi for Product Filter on 23rd July 2018
                return d.data.Color;

            }
            )
                .transition().duration(1000).attrTween("d", tweenIn).each("end", function (d) {
                    if (d.data != undefined)
                        this._listenToEvents = true;
                    else
                        this._listenToEvents = false;
                });

            // Mouse interaction handling
            paths.on("click", function (d) {
                // if (this._listenToEvents) {
                // Reset inmediatelly
                d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
                // Change level on click if no transition has started                
                paths.each(function () {
                    this._listenToEvents = false;
                });
                if (chartComponent.applyFiltering) {
                    paths.attr('fill', function (dt) {

                        return d.data.Color;

                    });
                }
                d['chartID'] = chartID;
                if (chartComponent.applyFiltering) {
                    chartComponent.chartClickEvent.emit(d);
                }
                return tooltip.style("display", 'none');
                //}
            })
                .on("mouseover", function (d) {
                    // Mouseover effect if no transition has started                
                    //if (this._listenToEvents) {
                    // Calculate angle bisector
                    var ang = d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / 2;
                    // Transformate to SVG space"text
                    ang = (ang - (Math.PI / 2)) * -1;
                    // Calculate a 10% radius displacement
                    var x = Math.cos(ang) * radius * 0.1;
                    var y = Math.sin(ang) * radius * -0.1;
                    //Added by Madhavi on 25th July 2018 for dragging the products in pie chart
                    // if (this.applyFiltering) {
                    d3.select(this).transition()
                        .duration(250).attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")");
                    // } commenting if condition for dragging the products in pie chart
                    //}
                    tooltip.text(d.data.Product + ' - ' + d.data.Value); return tooltip.style("display", null);
                })
                .on("mouseout", function (d) {
                    // Mouseout effect if no transition has started                
                    //  if (this._listenToEvents) {
                    d3.select(this).transition()
                        .duration(150).attr("transform", "translate(0,0)");
                    //}
                    return tooltip.style("display", "none");
                }).on("mousemove", function () { return tooltip.style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 10) + "px").style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 10) + "px"); });

            // Collapse sectors for the exit selection
            paths.exit().transition()
                .duration(1000)
                .attrTween("d", tweenOut).remove();
        }

        // "Fold" pie sectors by tweening its current start/end angles
        // into 2*PI
        function tweenOut(data) {
            data.startAngle = data.endAngle = (2 * Math.PI);
            var interpolation = d3.interpolate(this._current, data);
            this._current = interpolation(0);
            return function (t) {
                return arc(interpolation(t));
            };
        }

        // "Unfold" pie sectors by tweening its start/end angles
        // from 0 into their final calculated values
        function tweenIn(data) {
            var interpolation = d3.interpolate({
                startAngle: 0,
                endAngle: 0
            }, data);
            this._current = interpolation(0);
            return function (t) {
                return arc(interpolation(t));
            };
        }

        // Helper function to extract color from data object
        function getColor(data, index) {

            return data.Color;
        }

        function getTextWidth(text, fontSize, fontFace) {
            var a = document.createElement('canvas');
            var b = a.getContext('2d');
            b.font = fontSize + 'px ' + fontFace;
            return b.measureText(text).width;
        }
        // Start by updating graph at root level
        updateGraph(undefined);
        // document.getElementById("reDrawButton").addEventListener("click", reDrawChart);

    }

}
```

I have checked the data which is coming properly but still getting hell lot of errors. Please help!!
Data output in console is [image]

Comment: Can you please create a stackblitz of your code?

Answer (score 4):

Try specifying the data type when creating a new chart. Otherwise, the compiler will assume that data is of type `number`

```
export interface MyData
{
    Product: string;
    Color: string;
    Value: number;
}

//..... 


var pieChart = d3.pie<MyData>().sort(null)...
```

Answer (score 0):

When you trying to loop through data array, d3 pass each entry from array as "d"(you can name it whatever) to function, so you can directly read properties.
instead of reading d.data.Value you should read as d.Value, similarly change remaining properties also.

Comment: could you please specify which loop you are talking about by sharing a code snippet?

Comment: while drawing legend  you using data as   ".data(pieChart(data))" and after that to append text you using ".text(function (d) {}) . there you need to change similarly in remaining places also

Comment: this does not works for me. I am getting compilation error for `var pieChart = d3.pie().value(function (d) { return d.Value;}).sort(null),` could you please help with the complete solution ? Error when i type d.Value in above snippet is as follows: `Property 'Value' does not exist on type 'number | { valueOf(): number; }'.
  Property 'Value' does not exist on type 'number'.ts(2339)`