# D3 Pie Chart js in Angular

Tags: angular, d3.js

I am trying to achieve simple donut chart using D3 chart.js in angular. I'm following this link. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d3-js-donut-chart-l2w61a?file=src%2Fapp%2Fd3-donut%2Fd3-donut.component.ts

But I'm getting error in below code-

```
 var pie = this.d3.d3
  .pie()
  .sort(null) // Do not sort group by size
  .value(d => {
    return d.value;
  });
```

Error of Property 'Value' does not exist on type 'number'. Since I'm new to D3 js I'm unable to understand why we are getting this error. I tried as suggested in below link but it is not working. [Error of Property 'Value' does not exist on type 'number' in d3 Pie-chart in v4 using Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62803526/error-of-property-value-does-not-exist-on-type-number-in-d3-pie-chart-in-v4). Can anyone please help me to understand what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by using below code. I declared with  since giving exact class name was not working

```
 var pie = this.d3.d3
  .pie<any>()
  .sort(null) // Do not sort group by size
  .value(d => {
    return d.value;
  });
```